# Can't debug specific app network on iOS

Tags: ios, http, charles-proxy, burp

I have used Burp Suite and Charles to debug network using my computer as a proxy. It works with every app and it tracks all network requests, but there's a specific app where it's requests doesn't show up no matter what, does someone have any idea why? If the reason of this is the fact that the app makes SOAP requests, is there a way to track it?

Comment: Maybe your app is using secured connections (https)?

Comment: Yes it is. However, I'm already using a certificate and a private key to intermediate the connection. It doesn't works...

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Fozoro On my research, it seemed the reason of this is that the app was making requests to a soap server, which is connections oriented. I had to track the TCP connections which is kinda difficult. Here is a link explaining how it works: http://www.gilles-bertrand.com/2016/07/iphoneappwebtrafficcaptureproxymachttpsniffer.html?m=1         Please keep in mind that it’s not easy, try finding out the IP address the app is trying to access, it will make it easier.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!! by the way, you would know why burp suite is not catching IOS data that is sent through WebSockets?